# How the quality of clusters made in SPSS can be evaluated?

Tags: clustering, spss, model-based-clustering

How the quality of clusters made in SPSS with the method "TwoStep clustering" can be evaluated? Which test should be applied to be sure that the quality is good.

Comment: What is `quality of clusters` for you?

Comment: Evaluating the quality of clustering isn't specific to SPSS per se (althought you may want something pre-existing that you can click on). You might try reading through many of the site's existing relevant threads by searching for [clustering & evaluate](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=[clustering]+evaluate).